# Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm working on a React typescript project. The code works but ts compiler keeps complaining about my ref. Here is the code:

First I have a high order component to handle errors:

```
export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<ErrorBoundaryProps> {
    constructor(props: ErrorBoundaryProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
       // some error handling related code
    }

    public componentDidCatch(error: any) {
        // some error handling related code
    }

    public render() {
       return this.props.children;
    }
}
```

And a high order component:

```
export function withErrorBoundary<T = {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>): React.ComponentType<T> {
    function Wrapped(props: T) {
        return (
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <Component {...props} />
            </ErrorBoundary>
        );
    }
    return Wrapped;
}
```

This has worked well like this: `const NewComponent = withErrorBoundary(MyComponent)`

But now I'm building a new component that has the need of `React.forwardRef`:

```
interface ILabelProps {
  value: string;
  mark: boolean;
  // other props with basic types
}
export const Label = React.forwardRef(
    (props: ILabelProps, ref) => {
    React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        // some custom logic
    }), []);

    return (
        <>{...my UI}</>
    );
});

export MyLabel = withErrorBoundary(Label);
```

However when I use it like this it errors out about the ref:

**Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ILabelProps'**

```
const App = () => {
   const labelRef = React.useRef();
   return <MyLabel {...props} ref={labelRef} />
}
```

However if I just use `Label` without the `errorBoundary` HOC, it stops complaining:

```
const App = () => {
   const labelRef = React.useRef();
   return <Label {...props} ref={labelRef} />
}
```

I think the issue might be related the use of `React.forwardRef` because this is the first time I used it and I've never had this kind of issue before. Any one knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you need to designate a type for the `ref` that s being forwarded, but [I'm not seeing the error](https://tsplay.dev/W44R1W).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error when replicate your code.

But it does have 1 error at runtime:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. 
Attempts to access this ref will fail. 
Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Basically, your Component `MyLabel = withErrorBoundary(Label)` is the new Component returned from `withErrorBoundaray` hence it's lost the `forwardRef` provided by `Label`.
To fix that you just need to pass `labelRef` to `Label` Component like below:

```
  const MyLabel2 = withErrorBoundary(() => <Label {...props} ref={labelRef} />);
```

[Codesandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-hugle-khzqx?file=/src/App.tsx)